# Can't access component method after exporting by connect in React redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-ref

I have a React class component that has a method that I want to access later by using the provider. Below is the class

```
class ContactList extends Component {

  // props for contact

  renderContacts = () => {
    return // something
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        // something
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ contacts: state.contacts })

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ContactList);
```

I have another component where I am using `Provider` and want to access methods of `ContactList`, but I am not able to access it. Below is the block which I am using with the provider.

```
<Provider store={GridStore}>
  <ContactList
    ref={component => {
      window.reactContactListContainer = component
    }}
  />
</Provider>
```

When I try to do `window.reactContactListContainer.renderContacts()`, it is not able to find that method.

Answer (score 0):

`ref={callback}` syntax accepts a callback that is called with argument of type `HtmlElement` .

For example:

```
<div ref={divElement => window.divElement = divElement}>
  Test Ref
</div>
```

So, when you are calling: `window.reactContactListContainer.renderContacts()` it will throw an error, since `window.reactContactListContainer` is referencing to html element, not component itself.

If you want to call child function from parent, you have to use Context or some other approach

See more about ref callbacks in react docs [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

Answer (score 0):

The `connect` Higher Order Component needs to forward any passed React ref. It doesn't do this automatically so you will need to specify/configure `connect` to do this.

See [options](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object)

`options` is the ***fourth*** argument passed to `connect`.

```
class ContactList extends Component {

  // props for contact

  renderContacts = () => {
    return // something
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        // something
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ contacts: state.contacts })

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(ContactList);
```

[image: Edit cant-access-component-method-after-exporting-by-connect-in-react-redux]

### Note/Warning

This said, in addition to using really old "legacy" Redux code (*current standard is to use React function components and the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks with `React.forwardRef` and `React.useImperativeHandle`*) what you are trying to do here seems ***highly*** suspect and anti-pattern to established React design and usage. ***React components don't reach into and invoke internal functions of other React components.***

Since whatever it is you *really* want to do is obfuscated in the `// something` I can't speak more to what is a current and acceptable refactor.